# Rubocop - controller should subclass aplication controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I've got an API app so my `ApplicationController` inherit from `ActionController::API` :

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API; end`

But it turns out I need to have two views so I create new controller with two actions and corresponding views. To make it works my controller should inherit from `ActionController::Base`

```
class ClientsController < ActionController::Base
  def index; end

  def show; end
end
```

Which gets me Rubocop error:

`Rails/ApplicationController: Controllers should subclass 'ApplicationController'`

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: maybe you can turn that error off, at the top of the class you can add `# rubocop: disable Rails/ApplicationController`

Comment: I can exclude it in `rubocop.yml` but I think this is not a desirable solution.

Comment: yeah, that's right, maybe you can extend `ApplicationController` a little bit in order to add those views, take a look look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/API.html, in the section `Adding New Behavior`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I need a separate AuthController for the admin panel due to Api mode / ActionController::API instead of it extending off of ActionController::Base. Looking for a way around this warning but will just disable for now.